# error : Composer\Downloader\TransportException whem I try install Laravel

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php

Whem I excute this :$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel escola

The "https://packagist.org/p/paragonie/random_compat%2495bd167c03cf84009a9d2b78dbeaa976b3b236acbec52b60fe92d37ad096d860.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

This error appeared to me !! and I didn't get anything on the internet! a help please ?! (use linux distro ubuntu)

Comment: Did you tried to upgrade composer?

Comment: yes, but when I run this return :
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                     
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/p/provider2020-04%24a2008046841287393774299fae9.json"  file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Comment: Pretty strange, these URLs throw 404 errors for me too. But executing the given command works without any problems. Which version of Composer do you use?

Comment: helloo Nico.. I run as Root and everything is working!! tmks!

Answer (score -1):

run as Root work for me!! i think the problem is read/write perimission

Comment: helloo @MOHSEN.. tnks for report.. but I had to remove the Droplets and all works..
other thing I done,  chmod 644 id_rsa.pub and chmod 600 id_rsa